# .htaccess and mod_rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Have the following mod_rewrite rule:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
 RewriteRule ^index\.php$ / [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Which strips .php from any of my urls.

However, if I try to specify a 301 redirect to a page that already exists as such:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
 RewriteRule ^index\.php$ / [R=301,L]
 RewriteRule ^something-page\.php$ /something-page [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

The server can't resolve the domain.

I'm thinking I have seem to have put myself into a recursive loop.

Any help *much* appreciated!

Comment: Can you post the access logs just for a single request (and subsequent redirect) please?

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

This will redirect "/something-page" to "/soemthing-page.php", which will then in turn hit this:

```
RewriteRule ^something-page\.php$ /something-page [R=301,L]
```

Place the something-page rule above the generic .php rewrite rule, and mark it [L].

Comment: Thanks Drew, tried that - but to no avail I'm afraid. It still chokes on the URI.

Comment: So put the rewrite rule to the top - and marked it [L]. Still to no avail, seems to still process the generic ^(.*)$ $1.php.

Essentially google has indexed some of my /foo.php pages, which I'd obviously like to redirect 301 to /foo - but I can't seem to get the rule to work as expected.

Any help, would be much appreciated.